# php thrift hbase getRowWithColumnsTs

Tags: php, hbase, thrift

hbase row:

```
7  column=i:a, timestamp=1466665135061, value=2222                       
8  column=i:a, timestamp=1466664580715, value=222
```

php thfit:

```
getRowWithColumnsTs('table','8',array('i:a'), 1466665135061)
```

the result is:

```
8  column=i:a, timestamp=1466664580715, value=222
```

Why? The time is `1466665135061` but result is `1466664580715`.
How can the time be `1466665135061`?

thanks

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: More specifically, you should describe what are you doing and what is the expected result. Also, you're discussing some timestamps, so you have to specify what are they and why one number is expected and the other (that you get) looks impossible.